# Difference between 監督 and 管理 for "to control"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words, nuances, word-usage

So I think both 監督（かんとく）and 管理（かんり）are different from 経営（けいえい）in that 経営 refers to managing a business. However the word "control" can be used for many things in English:

1. To have control and power over an institution, like the government controlling the media or the banks
2. To control a remote-control item, although that could also be 操作（そうさ）
3. To prevent something from acting poorly or misbehaving, such as controlling a difficult situation or a rude child. E.g. "get your kid under control" or "I have the situation under control"
4. Monitoring or keeping an eye on something

Most of these probably have different words in Japanese, but I'm especially confused over definition 1.

Answer (score 2):

All these can be differentiated by having deeper understanding of `Kanji`.
But to simplify it:
監督 -　`Movie directors (映画監督)` comes in mind in most of the time, usually means a single person that is assigned a task to control. Or `監督する` to take control, usually in an environment/situation.

管理　- Has a very wide meaning of `to control/management`. Example `監督` is actually a part of `管理(職)`(Management) in an organization. `管理する` means `to manage`  more than `to control`.

経営 - Means exactly as you mentioned, is more of a position of managing business or `to manage` a business. It also has a general understanding of a higher position than `監督`

操作 - Rather than `control`, is more of a `manipulation` towards  `an object`/`a person`.

Comment: Isn't 映画監督 a movie director, not a producer?

Comment: @istrasci Yea you are right, edited the answers.